# R change date to a specific order

Tags: r, date, time

Date column in my data set starts with "2015-05-08 00:00:00" and ends with "2015-06-07 00:00:00". I would like to create a new column whose name will be day and order this column between 0-31.
"2015-05-08 00:00:00" should be 0
"2015-06-07 00:00:00" should be 31.

any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Data sample:

```
structure(list(Hour = structure(1:100, .Label = c("2015-05-08 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-08 01:00:00", "2015-05-08 02:00:00", "2015-05-08 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-08 04:00:00", "2015-05-08 05:00:00", "2015-05-08 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-08 07:00:00", "2015-05-08 08:00:00", "2015-05-08 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-08 10:00:00", "2015-05-08 11:00:00", "2015-05-08 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-08 13:00:00", "2015-05-08 14:00:00", "2015-05-08 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-08 16:00:00", "2015-05-08 17:00:00", "2015-05-08 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-08 19:00:00", "2015-05-08 20:00:00", "2015-05-08 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-08 22:00:00", "2015-05-08 23:00:00", "2015-05-09 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-09 01:00:00", "2015-05-09 02:00:00", "2015-05-09 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-09 04:00:00", "2015-05-09 05:00:00", "2015-05-09 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-09 07:00:00", "2015-05-09 08:00:00", "2015-05-09 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-09 10:00:00", "2015-05-09 11:00:00", "2015-05-09 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-09 13:00:00", "2015-05-09 14:00:00", "2015-05-09 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-09 16:00:00", "2015-05-09 17:00:00", "2015-05-09 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-09 19:00:00", "2015-05-09 20:00:00", "2015-05-09 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-09 22:00:00", "2015-05-09 23:00:00", "2015-05-10 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-10 01:00:00", "2015-05-10 02:00:00", "2015-05-10 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-10 04:00:00", "2015-05-10 05:00:00", "2015-05-10 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-10 07:00:00", "2015-05-10 08:00:00", "2015-05-10 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-10 10:00:00", "2015-05-10 11:00:00", "2015-05-10 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-10 13:00:00", "2015-05-10 14:00:00", "2015-05-10 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-10 16:00:00", "2015-05-10 17:00:00", "2015-05-10 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-10 19:00:00", "2015-05-10 20:00:00", "2015-05-10 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-10 22:00:00", "2015-05-10 23:00:00", "2015-05-11 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-11 01:00:00", "2015-05-11 02:00:00", "2015-05-11 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-11 04:00:00", "2015-05-11 05:00:00", "2015-05-11 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-11 07:00:00", "2015-05-11 08:00:00", "2015-05-11 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-11 10:00:00", "2015-05-11 11:00:00", "2015-05-11 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-11 13:00:00", "2015-05-11 14:00:00", "2015-05-11 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-11 16:00:00", "2015-05-11 17:00:00", "2015-05-11 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-11 19:00:00", "2015-05-11 20:00:00", "2015-05-11 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-11 22:00:00", "2015-05-11 23:00:00", "2015-05-12 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-12 01:00:00", "2015-05-12 02:00:00", "2015-05-12 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-12 04:00:00", "2015-05-12 05:00:00", "2015-05-12 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-12 07:00:00", "2015-05-12 08:00:00", "2015-05-12 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-12 10:00:00", "2015-05-12 11:00:00", "2015-05-12 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-12 13:00:00", "2015-05-12 14:00:00", "2015-05-12 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-12 16:00:00", "2015-05-12 17:00:00", "2015-05-12 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-12 19:00:00", "2015-05-12 20:00:00", "2015-05-12 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-12 22:00:00", "2015-05-12 23:00:00", "2015-05-13 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-13 01:00:00", "2015-05-13 02:00:00", "2015-05-13 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-13 04:00:00", "2015-05-13 05:00:00", "2015-05-13 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-13 07:00:00", "2015-05-13 08:00:00", "2015-05-13 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-13 10:00:00", "2015-05-13 11:00:00", "2015-05-13 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-13 13:00:00", "2015-05-13 14:00:00", "2015-05-13 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-13 16:00:00", "2015-05-13 17:00:00", "2015-05-13 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-13 19:00:00", "2015-05-13 20:00:00", "2015-05-13 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-13 22:00:00", "2015-05-13 23:00:00", "2015-05-14 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-14 01:00:00", "2015-05-14 02:00:00", "2015-05-14 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-14 04:00:00", "2015-05-14 05:00:00", "2015-05-14 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-14 07:00:00", "2015-05-14 08:00:00", "2015-05-14 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-14 10:00:00", "2015-05-14 11:00:00", "2015-05-14 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-14 13:00:00", "2015-05-14 14:00:00", "2015-05-14 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-14 16:00:00", "2015-05-14 17:00:00", "2015-05-14 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-14 19:00:00", "2015-05-14 20:00:00", "2015-05-14 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-14 22:00:00", "2015-05-14 23:00:00", "2015-05-15 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-15 01:00:00", "2015-05-15 02:00:00", "2015-05-15 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-15 04:00:00", "2015-05-15 05:00:00", "2015-05-15 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-15 07:00:00", "2015-05-15 08:00:00", "2015-05-15 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-15 10:00:00", "2015-05-15 11:00:00", "2015-05-15 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-15 13:00:00", "2015-05-15 14:00:00", "2015-05-15 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-15 16:00:00", "2015-05-15 17:00:00", "2015-05-15 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-15 19:00:00", "2015-05-15 20:00:00", "2015-05-15 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-15 22:00:00", "2015-05-15 23:00:00", "2015-05-16 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-16 01:00:00", "2015-05-16 02:00:00", "2015-05-16 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-16 04:00:00", "2015-05-16 05:00:00", "2015-05-16 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-16 07:00:00", "2015-05-16 08:00:00", "2015-05-16 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-16 10:00:00", "2015-05-16 11:00:00", "2015-05-16 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-16 13:00:00", "2015-05-16 14:00:00", "2015-05-16 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-16 16:00:00", "2015-05-16 17:00:00", "2015-05-16 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-16 19:00:00", "2015-05-16 20:00:00", "2015-05-16 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-16 22:00:00", "2015-05-16 23:00:00", "2015-05-17 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-17 01:00:00", "2015-05-17 02:00:00", "2015-05-17 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-17 04:00:00", "2015-05-17 05:00:00", "2015-05-17 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-17 07:00:00", "2015-05-17 08:00:00", "2015-05-17 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-17 10:00:00", "2015-05-17 11:00:00", "2015-05-17 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-17 13:00:00", "2015-05-17 14:00:00", "2015-05-17 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-17 16:00:00", "2015-05-17 17:00:00", "2015-05-17 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-17 19:00:00", "2015-05-17 20:00:00", "2015-05-17 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-17 22:00:00", "2015-05-17 23:00:00", "2015-05-18 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-18 01:00:00", "2015-05-18 02:00:00", "2015-05-18 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-18 04:00:00", "2015-05-18 05:00:00", "2015-05-18 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-18 07:00:00", "2015-05-18 08:00:00", "2015-05-18 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-18 10:00:00", "2015-05-18 11:00:00", "2015-05-18 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-18 13:00:00", "2015-05-18 14:00:00", "2015-05-18 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-18 16:00:00", "2015-05-18 17:00:00", "2015-05-18 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-18 19:00:00", "2015-05-18 20:00:00", "2015-05-18 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-18 22:00:00", "2015-05-18 23:00:00", "2015-05-19 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-19 01:00:00", "2015-05-19 02:00:00", "2015-05-19 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-19 04:00:00", "2015-05-19 05:00:00", "2015-05-19 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-19 07:00:00", "2015-05-19 08:00:00", "2015-05-19 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-19 10:00:00", "2015-05-19 11:00:00", "2015-05-19 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-19 13:00:00", "2015-05-19 14:00:00", "2015-05-19 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-19 16:00:00", "2015-05-19 17:00:00", "2015-05-19 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-19 19:00:00", "2015-05-19 20:00:00", "2015-05-19 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-19 22:00:00", "2015-05-19 23:00:00", "2015-05-20 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-20 01:00:00", "2015-05-20 02:00:00", "2015-05-20 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-20 04:00:00", "2015-05-20 05:00:00", "2015-05-20 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-20 07:00:00", "2015-05-20 08:00:00", "2015-05-20 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-20 10:00:00", "2015-05-20 11:00:00", "2015-05-20 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-20 13:00:00", "2015-05-20 14:00:00", "2015-05-20 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-20 16:00:00", "2015-05-20 17:00:00", "2015-05-20 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-20 19:00:00", "2015-05-20 20:00:00", "2015-05-20 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-20 22:00:00", "2015-05-20 23:00:00", "2015-05-21 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-21 01:00:00", "2015-05-21 02:00:00", "2015-05-21 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-21 04:00:00", "2015-05-21 05:00:00", "2015-05-21 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-21 07:00:00", "2015-05-21 08:00:00", "2015-05-21 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-21 10:00:00", "2015-05-21 11:00:00", "2015-05-21 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-21 13:00:00", "2015-05-21 14:00:00", "2015-05-21 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-21 16:00:00", "2015-05-21 17:00:00", "2015-05-21 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-21 19:00:00", "2015-05-21 20:00:00", "2015-05-21 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-21 22:00:00", "2015-05-21 23:00:00", "2015-05-22 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-22 01:00:00", "2015-05-22 02:00:00", "2015-05-22 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-22 04:00:00", "2015-05-22 05:00:00", "2015-05-22 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-22 07:00:00", "2015-05-22 08:00:00", "2015-05-22 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-22 10:00:00", "2015-05-22 11:00:00", "2015-05-22 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-22 13:00:00", "2015-05-22 14:00:00", "2015-05-22 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-22 16:00:00", "2015-05-22 17:00:00", "2015-05-22 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-22 19:00:00", "2015-05-22 20:00:00", "2015-05-22 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-22 22:00:00", "2015-05-22 23:00:00", "2015-05-23 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-23 01:00:00", "2015-05-23 02:00:00", "2015-05-23 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-23 04:00:00", "2015-05-23 05:00:00", "2015-05-23 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-23 07:00:00", "2015-05-23 08:00:00", "2015-05-23 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-23 10:00:00", "2015-05-23 11:00:00", "2015-05-23 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-23 13:00:00", "2015-05-23 14:00:00", "2015-05-23 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-23 16:00:00", "2015-05-23 17:00:00", "2015-05-23 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-23 19:00:00", "2015-05-23 20:00:00", "2015-05-23 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-23 22:00:00", "2015-05-23 23:00:00", "2015-05-24 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-24 01:00:00", "2015-05-24 02:00:00", "2015-05-24 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-24 04:00:00", "2015-05-24 05:00:00", "2015-05-24 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-24 07:00:00", "2015-05-24 08:00:00", "2015-05-24 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-24 10:00:00", "2015-05-24 11:00:00", "2015-05-24 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-24 13:00:00", "2015-05-24 14:00:00", "2015-05-24 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-24 16:00:00", "2015-05-24 17:00:00", "2015-05-24 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-24 19:00:00", "2015-05-24 20:00:00", "2015-05-24 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-24 22:00:00", "2015-05-24 23:00:00", "2015-05-25 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-25 01:00:00", "2015-05-25 02:00:00", "2015-05-25 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-25 04:00:00", "2015-05-25 05:00:00", "2015-05-25 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-25 07:00:00", "2015-05-25 08:00:00", "2015-05-25 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-25 10:00:00", "2015-05-25 11:00:00", "2015-05-25 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-25 13:00:00", "2015-05-25 14:00:00", "2015-05-25 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-25 16:00:00", "2015-05-25 17:00:00", "2015-05-25 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-25 19:00:00", "2015-05-25 20:00:00", "2015-05-25 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-25 22:00:00", "2015-05-25 23:00:00", "2015-05-26 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-26 01:00:00", "2015-05-26 02:00:00", "2015-05-26 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-26 04:00:00", "2015-05-26 05:00:00", "2015-05-26 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-26 07:00:00", "2015-05-26 08:00:00", "2015-05-26 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-26 10:00:00", "2015-05-26 11:00:00", "2015-05-26 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-26 13:00:00", "2015-05-26 14:00:00", "2015-05-26 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-26 16:00:00", "2015-05-26 17:00:00", "2015-05-26 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-26 19:00:00", "2015-05-26 20:00:00", "2015-05-26 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-26 22:00:00", "2015-05-26 23:00:00", "2015-05-27 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-27 01:00:00", "2015-05-27 02:00:00", "2015-05-27 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-27 04:00:00", "2015-05-27 05:00:00", "2015-05-27 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-27 07:00:00", "2015-05-27 08:00:00", "2015-05-27 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-27 10:00:00", "2015-05-27 11:00:00", "2015-05-27 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-27 13:00:00", "2015-05-27 14:00:00", "2015-05-27 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-27 16:00:00", "2015-05-27 17:00:00", "2015-05-27 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-27 19:00:00", "2015-05-27 20:00:00", "2015-05-27 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-27 22:00:00", "2015-05-27 23:00:00", "2015-05-28 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-28 01:00:00", "2015-05-28 02:00:00", "2015-05-28 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-28 04:00:00", "2015-05-28 05:00:00", "2015-05-28 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-28 07:00:00", "2015-05-28 08:00:00", "2015-05-28 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-28 10:00:00", "2015-05-28 11:00:00", "2015-05-28 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-28 13:00:00", "2015-05-28 14:00:00", "2015-05-28 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-28 16:00:00", "2015-05-28 17:00:00", "2015-05-28 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-28 19:00:00", "2015-05-28 20:00:00", "2015-05-28 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-28 22:00:00", "2015-05-28 23:00:00", "2015-05-29 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-29 01:00:00", "2015-05-29 02:00:00", "2015-05-29 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-29 04:00:00", "2015-05-29 05:00:00", "2015-05-29 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-29 07:00:00", "2015-05-29 08:00:00", "2015-05-29 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-29 10:00:00", "2015-05-29 11:00:00", "2015-05-29 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-29 13:00:00", "2015-05-29 14:00:00", "2015-05-29 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-29 16:00:00", "2015-05-29 17:00:00", "2015-05-29 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-29 19:00:00", "2015-05-29 20:00:00", "2015-05-29 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-29 22:00:00", "2015-05-29 23:00:00", "2015-05-30 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-30 01:00:00", "2015-05-30 02:00:00", "2015-05-30 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-30 04:00:00", "2015-05-30 05:00:00", "2015-05-30 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-30 07:00:00", "2015-05-30 08:00:00", "2015-05-30 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-30 10:00:00", "2015-05-30 11:00:00", "2015-05-30 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-30 13:00:00", "2015-05-30 14:00:00", "2015-05-30 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-30 16:00:00", "2015-05-30 17:00:00", "2015-05-30 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-30 19:00:00", "2015-05-30 20:00:00", "2015-05-30 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-30 22:00:00", "2015-05-30 23:00:00", "2015-05-31 00:00:00", 
"2015-05-31 01:00:00", "2015-05-31 02:00:00", "2015-05-31 03:00:00", 
"2015-05-31 04:00:00", "2015-05-31 05:00:00", "2015-05-31 06:00:00", 
"2015-05-31 07:00:00", "2015-05-31 08:00:00", "2015-05-31 09:00:00", 
"2015-05-31 10:00:00", "2015-05-31 11:00:00", "2015-05-31 12:00:00", 
"2015-05-31 13:00:00", "2015-05-31 14:00:00", "2015-05-31 15:00:00", 
"2015-05-31 16:00:00", "2015-05-31 17:00:00", "2015-05-31 18:00:00", 
"2015-05-31 19:00:00", "2015-05-31 20:00:00", "2015-05-31 21:00:00", 
"2015-05-31 22:00:00", "2015-05-31 23:00:00", "2015-06-01 00:00:00", 
"2015-06-01 01:00:00", "2015-06-01 02:00:00", "2015-06-01 03:00:00", 
"2015-06-01 04:00:00", "2015-06-01 05:00:00", "2015-06-01 06:00:00", 
"2015-06-01 07:00:00", "2015-06-01 08:00:00", "2015-06-01 09:00:00", 
"2015-06-01 10:00:00", "2015-06-01 11:00:00", "2015-06-01 12:00:00", 
"2015-06-01 13:00:00", "2015-06-01 14:00:00", "2015-06-01 15:00:00", 
"2015-06-01 16:00:00", "2015-06-01 17:00:00", "2015-06-01 18:00:00", 
"2015-06-01 19:00:00", "2015-06-01 20:00:00", "2015-06-01 21:00:00", 
"2015-06-01 22:00:00", "2015-06-01 23:00:00", "2015-06-02 00:00:00", 
"2015-06-02 01:00:00", "2015-06-02 02:00:00", "2015-06-02 03:00:00", 
"2015-06-02 04:00:00", "2015-06-02 05:00:00", "2015-06-02 06:00:00", 
"2015-06-02 07:00:00", "2015-06-02 08:00:00", "2015-06-02 09:00:00", 
"2015-06-02 10:00:00", "2015-06-02 11:00:00", "2015-06-02 12:00:00", 
"2015-06-02 13:00:00", "2015-06-02 14:00:00", "2015-06-02 15:00:00", 
"2015-06-02 16:00:00", "2015-06-02 17:00:00", "2015-06-02 18:00:00", 
"2015-06-02 19:00:00", "2015-06-02 20:00:00", "2015-06-02 21:00:00", 
"2015-06-02 22:00:00", "2015-06-02 23:00:00", "2015-06-03 00:00:00", 
"2015-06-03 01:00:00", "2015-06-03 02:00:00", "2015-06-03 03:00:00", 
"2015-06-03 04:00:00", "2015-06-03 05:00:00", "2015-06-03 06:00:00", 
"2015-06-03 07:00:00", "2015-06-03 08:00:00", "2015-06-03 09:00:00", 
"2015-06-03 10:00:00", "2015-06-03 11:00:00", "2015-06-03 12:00:00", 
"2015-06-03 13:00:00", "2015-06-03 14:00:00", "2015-06-03 15:00:00", 
"2015-06-03 16:00:00", "2015-06-03 17:00:00", "2015-06-03 18:00:00", 
"2015-06-03 19:00:00", "2015-06-03 20:00:00", "2015-06-03 21:00:00", 
"2015-06-03 22:00:00", "2015-06-03 23:00:00", "2015-06-04 00:00:00", 
"2015-06-04 01:00:00", "2015-06-04 02:00:00", "2015-06-04 03:00:00", 
"2015-06-04 04:00:00", "2015-06-04 05:00:00", "2015-06-04 06:00:00", 
"2015-06-04 07:00:00", "2015-06-04 08:00:00", "2015-06-04 09:00:00", 
"2015-06-04 10:00:00", "2015-06-04 11:00:00", "2015-06-04 12:00:00", 
"2015-06-04 13:00:00", "2015-06-04 14:00:00", "2015-06-04 15:00:00", 
"2015-06-04 16:00:00", "2015-06-04 17:00:00", "2015-06-04 18:00:00", 
"2015-06-04 19:00:00", "2015-06-04 20:00:00", "2015-06-04 21:00:00", 
"2015-06-04 22:00:00", "2015-06-04 23:00:00", "2015-06-05 00:00:00", 
"2015-06-05 01:00:00", "2015-06-05 02:00:00", "2015-06-05 03:00:00", 
"2015-06-05 04:00:00", "2015-06-05 05:00:00", "2015-06-05 06:00:00", 
"2015-06-05 07:00:00", "2015-06-05 08:00:00", "2015-06-05 09:00:00", 
"2015-06-05 10:00:00", "2015-06-05 11:00:00", "2015-06-05 12:00:00", 
"2015-06-05 13:00:00", "2015-06-05 14:00:00", "2015-06-05 15:00:00", 
"2015-06-05 16:00:00", "2015-06-05 17:00:00", "2015-06-05 18:00:00", 
"2015-06-05 19:00:00", "2015-06-05 20:00:00", "2015-06-05 21:00:00", 
"2015-06-05 22:00:00", "2015-06-05 23:00:00", "2015-06-06 00:00:00", 
"2015-06-06 01:00:00", "2015-06-06 02:00:00", "2015-06-06 03:00:00", 
"2015-06-06 04:00:00", "2015-06-06 05:00:00", "2015-06-06 06:00:00", 
"2015-06-06 07:00:00", "2015-06-06 08:00:00", "2015-06-06 09:00:00", 
"2015-06-06 10:00:00", "2015-06-06 11:00:00", "2015-06-06 12:00:00", 
"2015-06-06 13:00:00", "2015-06-06 14:00:00", "2015-06-06 15:00:00", 
"2015-06-06 16:00:00", "2015-06-06 17:00:00", "2015-06-06 18:00:00", 
"2015-06-06 19:00:00", "2015-06-06 20:00:00", "2015-06-06 21:00:00", 
"2015-06-06 22:00:00", "2015-06-06 23:00:00", "2015-06-07 00:00:00", 
"2015-06-07 01:00:00", "2015-06-07 02:00:00", "2015-06-07 03:00:00", 
"2015-06-07 04:00:00", "2015-06-07 05:00:00", "2015-06-07 06:00:00", 
"2015-06-07 07:00:00", "2015-06-07 08:00:00", "2015-06-07 09:00:00", 
"2015-06-07 10:00:00", "2015-06-07 11:00:00", "2015-06-07 12:00:00", 
"2015-06-07 13:00:00", "2015-06-07 14:00:00", "2015-06-07 15:00:00", 
"2015-06-07 16:00:00", "2015-06-07 17:00:00"), class = "factor"), 
    length = c(277L, 670L, 163L, 229L, 403L, 308L, 222L, 346L, 
    945L, 804L, 389L, 289L, 1288L, 530L, 1511L, 316L, 613L, 1191L, 
    278L, 242L, 77L, 21L, 17L, 26L, 35L, 79L, 131L, 356L, 225L, 
    206L, 141L, 33134L, 97093L, 453L, 263L, 284L, 1389L, 956L, 
    319L, 596L, 248L, 507L, 170L, 58L, 27L, 34L, 5L, 15L, 28L, 
    43L, 91L, 82L, 86L, 98L, 411L, 236L, 255L, 12788L, 89695L, 
    559L, 395L, 295L, 268L, 256L, 337L, 173L, 1038L, 96L, 20L, 
    11L, 10L, 38L, 58L, 98L, 209L, 320L, 175L, 252L, 293L, 164L, 
    168L, 208L, 221L, 837L, 232L, 559L, 348L, 439L, 1310L, 192L, 
    111L, 163L, 55L, 5L, 10L, 80L, 25L, 81L, 78L, 136L)), .Names = c("Hour", 
"length"), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: What did you try? Why did it not work?

Comment: Parse the dates so that they are of class `POSIXct` and then use `difftime`.

Comment: I had checked other questions and ı didn't come up with any idea so I didn't try any thing for solution @Heroka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert your `Hour` column to dates (dropping hours), then to factor and finally to numeric.

```
library(dplyr)
df$day <- as.Date(df$Hour) %>% as.factor %>% as.numeric
```